# $O_X$ is structural sheaf of affine scheme $X=Spec A$. Then $p\in Spec A$, $A_p\otimes O_X(U)\cong A_p$ for $p\in U\subset X$ as open subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, schemes

Let $X=Spec A$ be affine scheme. Then $O_{X,p}\cong A_p$ for $p\in Spec A$ and taking any $f\not\in p$, I have $A_f\otimes_{A_f}A_p\cong A_p$ as $A_f$ module. In particular $A_f=O_X(D(f))$.

My guess is that $O_X(D(f))\otimes_{A_f}A_p\cong A_p$ and $O_X(U)\otimes_{A_f}(A_p)=A_p$ for any open $U\subset D(f)$. $D(f)$ denotes basis of the topology.

Q1: Is the above assertion true? My guess is that $O_X(D(f))\to O_X(U)\to O_{X,p}$ is the module morphism I would like to consider. However, I did not figure out why $O_X(U)\otimes_{A_f}A_p\cong A_p$ should be the case.

Q2. If above is true, how do I prove it? If $O_X$ is flasque, then it surely holds. Under what circumstances, can I conclude that it holds?

Q3. Does it hold in general scheme construction?

Comment: If you do not require $p \in U$, this cannot be true, because it is clearly false for $U = \emptyset$.

Comment: @MooS Of course, I do need $p\in U$. And I want to say this is any open subset $U$ containing $p$ irregardless whether I am looking at $D(f)$ to start with.